# If $\kappa$ is a Markov kernel and $\mu$ is reversible with respect to $\kappa$, then the spectrum of $\kappa$ is contained in $[-1,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, markov-process, self-adjoint-operators

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$
- $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ reversible with respect to $\kappa$

Under this assumptions, $$\kappa f:=\int\kappa(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in L^2(\mu)$$ is a self-adjoint contraction. Let $$L^2_0:=\left\{f\in L^2(\mu):\int f\:{\rm d}\mu=0\right\},$$ $\kappa_0:=\left.\kappa\right|_{L^2_0}$ and $\sigma(\kappa_0)$ denote the spectrum of $\kappa_0$.

> Are we able to show that $\sigma(\kappa_0)\subseteq[-1,1)$.

**EDIT**: If I remember correctly, $$|\lambda|\le\left\|A\right\|_{\mathfrak L(X)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\lambda\in\sigma(A)$$ for any bounded linear operator $A$ on a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $X$. So, we should immediately obtain $\sigma(\kappa)\subseteq[-1,1]$ and $\sigma(\kappa_0)\subseteq[-1,1]$ by contractivity of $\kappa$.

Comment: Isn't this essentially just showing that $1 \not \in \sigma(\kappa_0)$, since the rest follows by an analogue of the Gerschgorin theorem?

Comment: @Ian Since I'm not aware of the theorem you're mentioning, I can't answer that question.

Comment: I'm saying that it should be more or less free that $\sigma(\kappa) \subseteq [-1,1]$; in the finite dimensional case this follows immediately from the Gerschgorin circle theorem.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your comment. I'll take a look at it. But usually the situation in infinite-dimension is more involved. If you know how we can prove $\sigma(\kappa_0)\subseteq[-1,1]$ that might be a good starting point.

Comment: @Ian Please take note of my edit. If I'm not missing something, $\sigma(\kappa)\subseteq[-1,1]$ and $\sigma(\kappa_0)\subseteq[-1,1]$ should easily follow from the contractivity.