# If $E$ is the spectral measure coresponding to a self-adjoint operator, show $\int1+2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n-i}nλ^idE(λ)f→\int\frac{1+λ}{1-λ}dE(λ)f$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a probability space, $\kappa$ be a contractive self-adjoint linear operator on $L^2(\mu)$ and $E:\mathbb R\to\mathfrak L(L^2(\mu))$ be the spectral family corresponding to $\kappa$. How can we show that $$\int 1+2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n-i}n\lambda^i\:{\rm d}E(\lambda)f\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\:{\rm d}E(\lambda)f\tag1$$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$? This looks like a simple application of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, but since the sum in the integrand on the left-hand side tends to $\infty$, I'm confused.

Comment: Why does the sum go to infinity? Since $\kappa$ is contractive you have that only $|\lambda|≤1$ contribute to the integral. Interpreting the word contractive in a more strict fashion ($\|\kappa\|<1$) will also cut off the integral before the problematic point $\lambda=1$.

Comment: @s.harp Well, it's not clear to me why the integral is $0$ outside $[-1,1]$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322373/47771.

Comment: Do you know that $\sigma(\kappa)\subseteq [-\|\kappa\|,\kappa\|]$? (For self-adjoint $\kappa$.)

Comment: @s.harp Yes. By self-adjointness, even $1\ge\left\|\kappa\right\|=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(\kappa)}|\lambda|$.

Comment: The relevant statement is that $E(\lambda)$ is an increasing family of projections, that becomes equal to $\Bbb 1$ at $\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(\kappa)}\lambda$. You would need to compare with the definition of the space associated to $E(\lambda)$ to note this.

Comment: @s.harp I know that $E(\lambda)\to\operatorname{id}_H$ ($H=L^2(\mu)$ here) as $\lambda\to\infty$ and that $E(\lambda)$ is a nondecreasing sequence of projections. But the relationship to the spectrum $\sigma(\kappa)$ is still unclear to me. The only relationship to the operator $\kappa$ I'm aware of is the requirement that $\int\lambda\:{\rm d}E(\lambda)f=\kappa f$.

Comment: @s.harp (And even when we assume that $|\lambda|\le1$, I still don't see why the sum converges.)

Comment: Ok, what you have is enough to see what I said. Suppose $dE(\lambda)$ has mass in some neighbourhood $U$ outside of $[-\|\kappa\|,\|\kappa\|]$. Let $x$ be a vector "gained" in this neighbourhood. Then
$$\|\kappa(x)\|= \|\int \lambda dE(\lambda)x\| = \|\int_U \lambda dE(\lambda)x\| ≥ \inf_{\lambda\in U}|\lambda| \|\int_UdE(\lambda)x\|=\inf_{\lambda\in U}|\lambda|\,\|x\|$$
now remember that $\inf_{\lambda\in U}|\lambda|≥\|\kappa\|$. This is a contradiction, so $dE(\lambda)$ has no mass outside of $[-\|\kappa\|,\|\kappa\|]$.

Comment: As to convergence: The sum certainly _does not_ converge for $\kappa=\Bbb 1$! Thats why I remarked that you should be looking for a more strict interpretation of the word "contraction" (namely $\|\kappa\|<1$).

Comment: @s.harp Unfortunately, my assumption is only $\left\|\kappa\right\|\le1$, but it seems like we can always shot what $1\not\in\sigma(\kappa)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3321311/47771.

Comment: @s.harp And the convergence isn't clear for me even when $\lambda\in[-1,1)$. It seems like you've got some geometric series argument in mind, but this is not an usual geometric sum... Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Note that the spectrum is closed, so if $1\not\in \sigma(\kappa)$ the spectrum terminates at a fixed point before the $1$. You can modify the argument above to show that $dE(\lambda)$ only has mass inside of $\sigma(\kappa)$ (I'm not sure what reference to give here, possibly Simon and Reed have a good chapter on the spectral theorem). As to the convergence, note that your sum is $(1-\frac1n)\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda^i = (1-\frac1n)(\frac{1+\lambda^{n+1}}{1-\lambda}-1)$, which does converge in the usual sense to $\frac{1}{1-\lambda}-1$.

Comment: @s.harp There was a typo in the sum: The $1$ was supposed to be an $i$, but I see that the convergence to $\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}$ holds whenever $|\lambda|<1$. However, from this it seems like we would even need to show that $-1\not\in\sigma(\kappa)$ (or that $\{-1\}$ is at least a null set). Moreover, it's not clear to me why the limit of integrals need to exist. I don't see an integrable dominator (and the integral on the right-hand side doesn't need to finite).